# htaccess non permanent redirect (301)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect every visitor that tries to enter my homepage (http://www.mysite.com/) to the `Pub` directory (http://www.mysite.com/Pub/)

**I want the url field to show http://www.mysite.com and not http://www.mysite.com/Pub/**

I've tried this, but for some reason it doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule / /Pub/
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here:
[how to mask URL with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611599/how-to-mask-url-with-htaccess)

long story short - it's impossible to show http://www.mysite.com and not http://www.mysite.com/Pub/.

Btw - you mean permanent redirect (301) or non permanent redirect (307)?

Answer (score 0):

Have your rule in .htacess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^/?$ /Pub/ [L]
```

It is important to not use `R` flag above so that its an internal redirect only without changing URL in the browser.